# Angular ng-select autocomplete how to provide option to "create new item" if No Items found?

Tags: javascript, angular, select, autocomplete, angular-ngselect

In ng-select (Angular), is there a way to provide "Create New" if no matches in the data list based on user search?

I like to create new items like the reference image below when no matches are found.

[image]

As per ng select config, we have the option to set only text for not Found Text  (notFoundText). I didn't have any HTML Template option to provide.

Any suggestions?

Ng-select Stackblitz  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-not-fount-text-not-working-5gcdlq?file=src%2Fbindings-default-example.component.ts,src%2Fbindings-default-example.component.html

Comment: Can you check the new Link ?

Comment: @SouhailChougrani New link ??

Comment: @SouhailChougrani Thans Souhail. My bad. I didn't check the new link. I got the options. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass a template like below.

```
<ng-select 
[items]="defaultBindingsList" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"

>
<ng-template ng-notfound-tmp let-searchTerm="searchTerm">
<div class="ng-option disabled">
    No data found for "{{searchTerm}}". Do you want to create new?
    <button>Create New</button>
</div>
</ng-template>
</ng-select>
```